# How to select and change every other row's value of a particular column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an idea of how to do this but I'm getting stuck putting it all together. I tried:

```
df[::2, 'my_column'] = 0
```

Because I want to take every other row (i.e. the "::2" selector) of a specific column ('my_column'), and set those values to something (0).

Error:

> pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, 2), 'my_column')

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to to it

```
df.loc[::2, 'my_column'] = 0
```

Comment: Hrm, beat me by 5 seconds. I've deleted mine, we don't need two identical answers.